# Android install .apk from sdcard programmatically error - Package Parse error

Tags: android

I'm trying to install .apk file stored at External storage under the Download folder with the following code. I got an error dialog with the message there was a problem while parsing the package. I'm using production .apk file downloaded from google play store and also debug .apk file. For both files, I'm getting the same error screen while installing .apk programmatically. Manually I can install the same .apk file so there is no issue in the file. I have even made this application a **Device Owner** application but it still doesn't work. Is there any way to install .apk file?

```
            Uri mUri_ = Uri.parse(filePath);
            String packageName = "com.neo.apkinstaller";
            context.grantUriPermission(packageName, mUri_, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            try {
                Intent appInstallerIntent = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    appInstallerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    appInstallerIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(inst_path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                } else {
                    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.neo.apkinstaller", new File(inst_path));
                    appInstallerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                    appInstallerIntent.setData(uri);
                    appInstallerIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
                appInstallerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                context.startActivity(appInstallerIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

file provider declaration in **Manifest.xml** file:

```
<provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="com.neo.apkinstaller"
                android:exported="false"
                android:multiprocess="true"
                android:process="@string/process"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**provider_paths.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>

    <external-path
            name="external_files"
            path="."/>

    <files-path
            name="files"
            path="/"/>

    <cache-path
            name="cache"
            path="/"/>

    <external-files-path
            name="external_files"
            path="."/>


    <external-cache-path
            name="external_cache"
            path="."/>


    <files-path
            name="tmp"
            path="tmp/"/>

    <root-path
            name="sdcard1"
            path="." />
</paths>
```

**Error screenshot**
[image]
TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the end of this youtube-tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmOQ0EUwXjA&list=PLemXnOew0Zz3PZY48lWHpWKMT5_D8844D&index=4&t=0s
There an apk is installed programatically.
You can ignore the first part with the dropbox stuff ;)

The source code is:

```
private void AutoUpdate (String NameOfNewApplication, String downloadPathFrom)
{
    DropboxDownloadPathTo = NameOfNewApplication;
    DropboxDownloadPathFrom = downloadPathFrom;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download file ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    File file = new File(DropboxDownloadPathTo + DropboxDownloadPathFrom.substring(DropboxDownloadPathFrom.lastIndexOf('.')));
                    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        main.dropboxAPI.getFile(DropboxDownloadPathFrom, null, outputStream, null);
                        getMain().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File successfully downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(file.exists())
                    {
                        while (file.length() == 0)
                        {
                            try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
            th.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: even with the same Intent call I'm getting a parsing package error in Lenovo K5 note (Android M). and above android N we need a file provider.